# mount_smbfs fails in crontab with "mount_smbfs: unable to open connection: syserr = Authentication error"

Tags: cron, freebsd, smb

I want a FreeBSD machine to mount a SMB share from a Linux server automatically after boot. Hence I wrote a script to run in the root crontab to mount it. I have set the require credential and IP on the */root/.nsmbrc* and script runs fine on command line. However, it fails when being called from crontab with the following error.

> mount_smbfs: unable to open connection: syserr = Authentication error

The content of the file */root/.nsmbrc*

```
[default]
workgroup=WORKGROUP

[UBUNTU]
addr=192.168.1.20
charsets=UTF-8:UTF-8

[UBUNTU:FREEBSD]
password=[***trimmed***]
```

The mounting line

```
/usr/sbin/mount_smbfs -N -f 666 -d 777 //freebsd@ubuntu/share /net/ubuntu/share
```

How do I fix it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you consider to use `/etc/fstab` because this is the place where are defined mounted filesystems

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the FreeBSD operating system and its utilities should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask there.

Comment: @Remeo, the major drawback of /etc/fstab is, the system cannot boot up when it failed to mount a share. As a shared directory on another networked machine, the risk of a failed system is too much to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `/etc/fstab`, for example with something like:

```
//u123@u123/foo /mnt/foo smbfs rw,late,-N 0 0
```

> If   the option "late" is specified, the file system will be automatically
>        mounted at a stage of system startup after remote mount points are
>        mounted.  (`man fstab`)

Then in `/etc/nsmb.conf` you could have something like:

```
[U123]
addr=192.168.1.20
retry_count=100
timeout=30
[U123:U123]
password=secret
```

Comment: Thanks nbari. However, as the natural of a network share is inherently unreliable, any failure of mounting that drive renders the freebsd box unbootable. It is too much risk to do so.

Comment: @crackpot If you are worried about waiting at boot time, you could use either the option `late` or `noauto`, you could find some examples in the man of `mount_smbfs`